# Excel VBA | Userform that updates an selected row on an Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm working on a basic userform project to learn and use it on my actual database for business.

a. I have created two userforms;

- UserForm1 = Adding data to last row, show data on a listbox and deletes a row
- UserForm2 = You can open it from on UserForm1 (I named "Edit")

b. The data that I have basically 4 columns and values;

```
ID  ||  Name  || Last Name || Date
```

When you click the "Edit" button on that and the row that you want to update data on listbox, it will open 3 textboxes with which you can change `ID`, `Name`, and `Last Name`. Additionally there is a "Save" button

I have a code that I made with an youtuber but what he did was he remains the ID column with Label and you can not change it, just shows the value.

What I want to do is I want to change all values (`ID`, `Name`, `Last Name`) not just `Name` and `Last Name`?
I tried and searched a lot but what all I did had not worked. Here is my code;

The Edit Button's code on UserForm1

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    UserForm2.Label4.Caption = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex) ' I wanted to update this data also
    UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Column(1, ListBox1.ListIndex)
    UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.Column(2, ListBox1.ListIndex)
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Save Button Code on UserForm2

```
'When I make changes on this, It updates all rows with the entered values. This is original code that I want to make changes.

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = Label4.Caption Then
        Cells(i, 2) = TextBox1.Text
        Cells(i, 3) = TextBox2.Text
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Saved!", vbInformation
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: So right now you have two `textboxes` and one `label`, and you wish to have three textboxes instead? Why not replace the label by a textbox then?

Comment: Yep, I had tried it but after that I have to change the If statement. So I got stuck on that. I couldn't understand to what to write on UserForm2

Comment: Well if you remove the `label` then `If Cells(i, 1) = Label4.Caption Then` becomes nonsense as there is no label to refer to

Comment: So will be work like this?

For i = 2 To Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = TextBox1.Text Then
        Cells(i, 2) = TextBox2.Text
        Cells(i, 3) = TextBox3.Text
    End If
Next i

Comment: I would assume so, yes

Comment: I tried this one but It not changes cell values :( Can I share the file here ?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the correct textbox? Use `F8` to step through the code to see what values you are comparing with

Comment: I'm shame on that :) thanks for your help a lot. When it happens like this I'm getting nervous and starting try another code options and got stuck. Have a nice day!